# Angular lifecycle error - incorrectly implements interface 'DoCheck'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to implement the angular lifecycle hooks and I keep getting these errors relating to angular lifecycle implementation interface.

> Class 'LifecycleComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'DoCheck'.

This is my component code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy, DoCheck, AfterContentChecked, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lifecycle',
  templateUrl: './lifecycle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lifecycle.component.css']
})
export class LifecycleComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy, DoCheck, AfterContentChecked, AfterContentInit  {

dataOnInit = 0;
dataOnChanges = 0;
dataOnDestroy = 0;
dataDoCheck = 0;
dataAfterContentChecked = 0;
dataAfterContentInit = 0;

constructor() { }

OnInit(): void {
  this.dataOnInit += 1;
  console.log(`OnInit called ${this.dataOnInit} times!`);
}

OnChanges(): void {
  this.dataOnChanges += 1;
  console.log(`OnChanges called ${this.dataOnChanges} times!`);
}

Destroy(): void {
  this.dataOnDestroy += 1;
  console.log(`OnDestroy called ${this.dataOnDestroy} times!`);
}

DoCheck(): void {
  this.dataDoCheck += 1;
  console.log(`DoCheck called ${this.dataDoCheck} times!`);

}
AfterContentChecked(): void {
  this.dataAfterContentChecked += 1;
  console.log(`AfterContentChecked called ${this.dataAfterContentChecked} times!`);

}
AfterContentInit(): void {
  this.dataAfterContentInit += 1;
  console.log(`AfterContentInit called ${this.dataAfterContentInit} times!`);
}
```

Comment: Searched everywhere but couldn't find the simple mistake done here. Hope it'll help someone

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what's wrong here is how those events are called. Imported names can't be directly used as the event function. E.g.

```
DoCheck(): void { console.log('DoCheck'); } // this is incorrect!
```

You are suppose to add the `ng` prefix when calling those angular lifecycle events. E.g.

```
ngDoCheck(): void { console.log('DoCheck'); }
```